# change the value of useState with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-state

I have a simple component with `useState` that increase a counter in each click -

```
function Counter() {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incCounter = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{counter}</h1>

      <button onClick={incCounter}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is its demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-1k2hn)

and now I want to call the increase function each 1 second , so I added this piece of code into the component function -

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      incCounter();
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

[Here is its demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-x9g8f?file=/src/index.js)

but I don't see the counter increased in the component.

How should I write it correctly and see the counter increased in each 1 second as expected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Issue

You've a stale enclosure of the state value from the render cycle the timer callback was set from.

## Solution

Use a functional state update so the state is updated from the previous state, not the state from the render cycle the update was enqueued in. This allows the interval callback ***and*** click handler to seamlessly update state, independently from each other.

```
setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
```

In fact, you should use a functional state update *anytime* the next state value depends on any previous state value. Incrementing a counter is the classic example of using functional updates.

Don't forget to return a cleanup function to clear the interval for when the component umnounts.

Full code

```
function Counter() {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incCounter = () => {
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(() => {
      incCounter();
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{counter}</h1>

      <button onClick={incCounter}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit change-the-value-of-usestate-with-setinterval]

Comment: Great answer, I would only like to add a cleanup of the interval in the `useEffect` hook

Comment: @nbokmans Unrelated to issue but great and valid point about proper lifecycle maintenance, updated answer. Thanks.